# Ktor Secure Sockets (SSL/TLS) windows example?

Tags: sockets, ssl, kotlin, ktor

I was trying to follow the ktor documentation for Raw Sockets and in specific the part related to secured sockets (https://ktor.io/servers/raw-sockets.html):

```
runBlocking {
    val socket = aSocket(ActorSelectorManager(ioCoroutineDispatcher)).tcp().connect(InetSocketAddress("google.com", 443)).tls()
    val w = socket.openWriteChannel(autoFlush = false)
    w.write("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n")
    w.write("Host: google.com\r\n")
    w.write("\r\n")
    w.flush()
    val r = socket.openReadChannel()
    println(r.readUTF8Line())
}

You can adjust a few optional parameters for the TLS connection:

suspend fun Socket.tls(
        trustManager: X509TrustManager? = null,
        randomAlgorithm: String = "NativePRNGNonBlocking",
        serverName: String? = null,
        coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = ioCoroutineDispatcher
): Socket
```

But the **NativePRNGNonBlocking** SecureRandom algorithm is not available on Windows, so my only option was to use **SHA1PRNG** (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SecureRandomImp)

**This is the code I'm running to connect to a listening socket :**

```
socket = aSocket(ActorSelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)).tcp().connect(InetSocketAddress(host, port))
    .tls(Dispatchers.IO, randomAlgorithm = "SHA1PRNG")
```

Unfortunately, I always receive the same error: "**Channel was closed**"

If I remove tls, keeping only the raw socket:

```
socket = aSocket(ActorSelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)).tcp().connect(InetSocketAddress(host, port))
```

Everything works as expected.

Does anyone has used Ktor Secure Sockets in Windows ? (Unfortunately, Ktor's documentation still has a long way to go).

Thanks, 
J